# Understanding Martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Why is the equation $E[X_s|\mathcal{F_s}] = X_s$? I understand the algebraic manipulations that get $E[X_t|\mathcal{F_s}] = X_s$ but can't build intuition on what the point of having a conditional expectation - given the filtration - is if it's just gonna be that it's constant.

An application of this fact would be useful. If,  $E[X_s|\mathcal{F_s}] = X_s$ then is the $X_s$ on the RHS still a random variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to remember that the conditional expectation is a random variable (hence not constant) that acts as the projection on presupposed information. So in your case $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]$ is the 'projection' of $X_t$ as an $L^1$-function onto the subspace of $L^1$-functions that is 'known' up to time $s$ - the closest random variable to $X_t$ whose values are known from $\mathcal{F}_s$. To say that $E[X_s|\mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$ is simply to say that we already know all that is to know from $X_s$ at time $s$ so any added information at time $s$ (that is $\mathcal{F}_s$) is redundant: the projection of an element on the projected subspace is identical. Thus your intuition is correct in some sense that it is trivial (by adaptedness), but that the martingle-property $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$ is highly non-trivial in the sense of projections. Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability* treats conditional expectations in this way.

It is also important to realize here the dependence of martingales and its filtration, that is that projecting a random variable onto any other 'known information' may inhibit the martingale property.

Comment: That's an interesting take on it. Is there a notes shortened version of this 'Kallenberg's Foundations of modern probability'? Also I'm right to say that $X_s$ is still a random variable? The unintuitive part is that the expectation can be a random variable again. But I see now with these 'projections' you made how that is possible. is it sensible to say that $E_\mathcal{F_s}[X_s|\mathcal{F_s}] = E[X_s|\mathcal{F_s}]$

Comment: Yes it is sensible to write $E_{\mathcal{F}_s} X = E[X|\mathcal{F}_s]$, and to view $E_{\mathcal{F}_s}$ as an _operator_ from $L^1$ to $L^1$. Yes, the step from expectations (as real-valued) to conditional expectation (as random variables) is tricky at first, but it makes sense because conditional expectation depends on the outcome and whether the outcome belongs to the conditioned information (since then we know something extra). So $X_s$ is still a random variable, by definition. As conditional expectations are random variables all equalities involved are taken 'almost surely'.

Comment: For a free link to Kallenberg and conditional expectations, see Theorem 5.1 in the link below. It is a standard reference.

http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Math%20Complete/Probability%20and%20statistics/Foundations%20of%20Modern%20Probability%20-%20Olav%20Kallenberg.pdf

Comment: Is a filtration then just a random variable or a set of random variables? I still have this uneasy feeling of why it is itself - the expectation - now due to what the filtration $\mathcal{F_s}$ itself could be. I know I can just read the book; is it worth it?

Comment: @KidCudi Measure theoretic (modern) probability is difficult to get a hang of, I would suggest reading a book. The technical answer is that a filtration is an inclusion monotone family of sigma algebras. At each $\mathcal{F}_s$ we have a family of sets (sigma algebra), _events_, and at each further time step we know more events. A filtration is essentially the family of known events evolving with time. Whenever we condition on a random we take the generated sigma algebra of the random variable. Again, look into some standard text on probability.